# What does "/ union" means while making kali persistence drive

Tags: linux, kali-linux

There is a command echo "/ union" > /mnt/UUI/persistence.conf while making kali persistence drive. What does "/ union" means why is it used?

Comment: `/` Is the root and `union` will concatenate multiple sequences into a single sequence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`union` stands for [unionfs](http://unionfs.filesystems.org). It is a filesystem that allows transparently overlaying of two or more filesystems. This can be used for, e.g., overlaying a read-write filesystem on top of a read-only one, thus allowing files in the read-only FS to be modified with the modifications actually written (i.e., persisted) to the read-write FS.